# Behaviour of strtotime(+1 month) and December/next year

Tags: php, strtotime

I am working with php and have to compare some data created between the first of the current month and the first of the next month.

I use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));` to get the first of the next month. Does this mean that I get the January 1st 2019 when the current date is e.g. 2018-12-16? Or does `strtotime('+1 month')` just adds the next month and ignores the year, so the result would be 2018-01-16...?

I am not sure, if this is the way `strtotime('+1 month')` works and I can't test it with a hardcoded month; `date('Y-12-d', strtotime('+1 month'));` returns 2018-12-28... Did I even test it in the correct way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i suggest reading the docs in detail, with the user notes, for example [this one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#107331) or [this other](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php#103206). And do tests in a separate script. Some quirks with months can produce unexpected results

Comment: answer is yes, it does not ignore the year
it's just like a basic increment except it is date

Comment: Yep, I already read about the month-skipping problem, but I hope I solved it with hardcoding the first of the month. Gonna do some further tests. @Beginner thanks!

Comment: _“Does this mean that”_ ... you was simply to lazy to just test it yourself?!?

Comment: If you would've read it correctly, You would've noticed that I indeed tested it myself. But i couldn't test the December scenario, thats why I was asking. Don't assume I am lazy just becuz YOU are too lazy to read what I wrote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime('+1 month')` add the 1 month in current month, for example

if current date is 2018-06-28 then

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));
```

**Output** is :

```
2018-07-28
```

If you want first date of month then use :

```
echo date('Y-m-01', strtotime('+1 month')); // +1 month (Jun to July)
```

or

```
echo date('Y-m-01'); // Return Current Month
```

If current month is `December` and you add 1 month with `strtotime('+1 month')` then your date will be in next year

Comment: Yes I know, I actually use it like this: date('Y-m-01'). But my question was about December and the +1 month. Do I have to think about an extra solution because strtotime does not work correctly when adding +1 month to December or is there nothing to worry about?

Comment: If current month is December and you do +1 month with `strtotime` then your date will be in next year

Comment: Thank you for the answer